# Is there a better way to get the folder structure of a repo than using Github api when using Github pages?

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to build a portal using Github pages and I want the buttons in my page to be generated based on what folders are present in Github repo, one way is to use Github api to get the tree, I was wondering if there was a way to do this using JavaScript and Github pages.

I don't want to use the API if I don't have to and since I am working with Github pages anyway, I was hoping there was a way to get the folder structure of a repo, using that.

Comment: How are you building this portal? What tools are you using?

Comment: I am using React and will later publish this to GIthub Pages. Since this is GIthub pages, I can only use client side technologies and so am limited to Javascript and can't use stuff like NodeJS.